# Apicontroller - how to get access to methods such as Json() and Content()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

Usually when I work with ASP.NET MVC in normal controllers, I have access to methods such as return `Json()` or `Content()`.

These methods are useful for when to return an actionresult. However, when having an API controller, these methods seems not to be there. I guess they lives in the BaseController, the normal controllers inherit from?

How do you usually in an easy way to return JSON/XML/similar when working with an Apicontroller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With web api you dont specify the representation sent to the client. Webapi supports content negotiation which means the client can request any of those representations from the server simply by sending the correct accept header.

see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Web API returns Json/XML content types by default.

The client can control which content type they want to get by setting required `accept-header` i.e (`application/xml or application/JSON`) in the api request.

For example if the client make a request like this, api will return response in JSON format

```
GET http://localhost:1234/api/products HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost.:1234  
Accept: application/json
```

If client make request with header like this, api will return response in XML format

```
GET http://localhost:1234/api/products HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost.:1234  
Accept: application/xml
```

Comment: content-type is used to specify the type of a post, accept headers are used to give preference to specific types being sent to the client